# Why does my program hang when calling function from socket callback?

Tags: c#, sockets, singleton

I'm trying to access a wrapper for a Collection type(ModuleManager.cs) from a socket callback function. Whenever a client connects to this socket, I want it to give some data about itself to put it and it's socket into the ModuleManager.

```
private static void AddModule (StateObject state)
    {
        string[] ModuleInfo = state.sb.ToString().Split('|');

        // Create the module object.
        Module module = new Module();
        module.Socket = state.workSocket;
        module.Name = ModuleInfo[0];
        module.Plugin = PluginManager.PluginManager.Current.GetPlugin(ModuleInfo[1].Substring(0, ModuleInfo[1].Length - 5));


        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\log.txt", System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " -> [ModuleFinder] Adding module : " + state.sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        ModuleManager.Current.Add(module);
    }
```

So basically the data to create the Module is in the state stringbuilder. The Module is created and then added to the ModuleManager:

```
    public void Add(Module module)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\log.txt", System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " -> [ModuleManager] Adding Module: " + module.Name + " | " + module.Plugin.Name + Environment.NewLine);
        if (ModuleManager.Current.GetModule(module.Name) == null && PluginManager.PluginManager.Current.GetPlugin(module.Plugin) != null)
        {
            Modules.Add(module);
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\log.txt", System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " -> [ModuleManager] Added Module: " + module.Name + " | " + module.Plugin.Name + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

As you might have noticed, a logfile is created in the process, since the last log never gets appended I came to the conclusion that the program gets stuck on

```
Modules.Add(module)
```

But I have no idea why. When I then check the WebApp to see if there are any registered modules, no result.

The full project on git: https://github.com/LarsGardien/EniacHome

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `ModuleManager.Current.GetModule(module.Name)` doing?

Comment: Singletons can be shared within an app domain; if your projects are all loaded into the same app domain, they can all share the same singleton. But it's not clear that's really what your question is anyway. You seem instead to be trying to debug a hang in your program. But without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, I doubt much good help will be possible, never mind forthcoming.

Comment: @Rob, I check wether a module with the same name has been registered before.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I know I'm not exactly clear on the problem. But that's because I don't really get the problem myself either. For some reason when I debug the ModuleManager.Add() function, it doesn't break on anything when being called from the socket callback. But when it is called from somewhere else there seems to be no problem at all

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. You also don't get the log line if the `if` clause is not executed. This is very likely the case because I could not find any issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the problem. I wasn't listening for modules on a different thread, so some weird behaviour showed up. Sorry for the nebulous question. I just couldn't put it the way i wanted..